# Using .remove in a loop in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the following code:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for x in arr:
  if x > 3:
    arr.remove(x)

print(arr)
```

It gives the following output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

While instead i thought it would remove from the array every element bigger than 3. Why is that? And how can i make it remove every element bigger than a certain amount?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying a list that you're in the process of iterating over will frequently yield unexpected results.  A better option is to create a new list:

```
arr = [x for x in arr if x <= 3]
```

Comment: Am i forced to create a new variable for that? I'm pretty new to Python, and i'm struggling to understand why does this happen

Comment: There is no new variable created in that example; I'm reassigning `arr`, the variable name you already used.

Comment: The thing the above code does differently from your `for` loop is that a completely new list is created by the comprehension expression on the right before being assigned to `arr`.  The original `arr` list is never modified; we just generate a new list based on it, and then replace the entire thing.

Comment: Got it, thank you!